# how to vertically center facebook line iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

whats wrong with this code? i cannot vertically center it using any style. I want it to use style attribut instead of modifying css.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/KOMPAScom&layout=button" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:47px; height:20px"></iframe>
```

heres when i try style attribut:

```
<iframe style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/feednews.id&layout=button" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:47px; height:20px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="d" style="position:relative;width:500px;height:500px;border:solid blue;">
<iframe style="position:relative;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);border:solid red;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/feednews.id&layout=button" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden" id="fb"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the iframe in a div and set the style with text-align:center.

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
<iframe src="about:blank" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:47px; height:20px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Note that you also have two style statements in the same element. Only one of those will be taken into consideration.

Comment: Note the 'vertical' part